# Transitioning fragment calls exit transition but animation is not happening

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, transition

I want to have a custom animation when moving from fragment A to fragment B

```
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content, fragmentA).commit();
```

later

```
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content, fragmentB).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

I cannot use ft.setCustomAnimations() as this will animate the whole fragmentA and i want to animate each individual view inside it.
This means AFAIK that i need to use transitions

so my fragments have

```
    Transition transition = new MyTransition();
    setEnterTransition(transition);
    setReenterTransition(transition);
    //setReturnTransition(transition);
    setExitTransition(transition);
```

All this is fine as the transition runs both on enter and exit

My transition class

```
private class MyTransition extends Transition
{
    private Interpolator accelerate = new AccelerateInterpolator();
    private Interpolator decelerate = new DecelerateInterpolator();
    boolean entering = false;

    @Override
    public void captureStartValues(TransitionValues transitionValues)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void captureEndValues(TransitionValues transitionValues)
    {

    }

    private void showing(boolean showing)
    {
        if (entering == showing) return;
        entering = showing;
        if (entering)
        {
            setDuration(Application.ANIMATION_DURATION);
            setInterpolator(decelerate);
        }
        else
        {
            setDuration(Application.ANIMATION_DURATION);
            setInterpolator(accelerate);
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Animator createAnimator(@NonNull ViewGroup sceneRoot, @Nullable TransitionValues startValues, @Nullable TransitionValues endValues)
    {
        if (endValues != null)
        {
            showing(true);
            View target = endValues.view;
            switch(target.getId())
            {
                case R.id.fab:
                    return ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(target,
                            PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", 1f),
                            PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", 1f));
                case R.id.main_player_tools:
                    return ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(target, "translationX", 0);
                case R.id.main_score:
                    return ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(target, "translationY", 0);
                case R.id.main_custom:
                    return ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(target, "translationX", 0);
                case R.id.main_dice:
                    return ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(target, "translationY", 0);
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if (startValues != null)
        {
            showing(false);
            View target = startValues.view;
            switch(target.getId())
            {
                case R.id.fab:
                    return ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(target,
                            PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", 0f),
                            PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", 0f));
                case R.id.main_player_tools:
                    return ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(target, "translationX", -target.getWidth());
                case R.id.main_score:
                    return ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(target, "translationY", -target.getHeight());
                case R.id.main_custom:
                    return ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(target, "translationX", target.getWidth());
                case R.id.main_dice:
                    return ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(target, "translationY", target.getHeight());
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Running with the debugger the code seems to proceed correctly:

When starting fragmentA i see the code going in createAnimator and creating each animator accordingly. When starting fragmentB, again everything seems to execute fine.
However on the phone i only see the enter animation. When it's going to start the exit animation the fragmentA instantly disappears and the enter animation of fragmentB is playing.

Any ideas why?

I've tried to increase duration of exit animation, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

The reason was that i wasn't capturing values nor was i overriding getTransitionProperties.

This caused isTransitionRequired to return false and causes the animation to be ignored.

Be careful when capturing values.
If start and end values are the same the transition will not be executed.